# Asynchronously iterating line-by-line through a file

Tags: swift, swift5, foundation, wwdc

In the ["Platforms State of the Union" video of WWDC2021](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/102) at 28:00 it was mentioned that

> [Apple] even added support for asynchronously iterating line-by-line through a file

in Foundation for macOS 12/iOS 15 and Swift 5.5.

What is that new API, how can I now asynchronously iterate line-by-line through a file?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/ ?

Comment: @Larme Already watched that, there wasn't any mention of the API I'm looking for.

Comment: or https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/101/ (at 1:38)? Its await/async? It's not really an API, it's in the language I'd say. And the related topic on the previous link: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0300-continuation.md etc. ?

Comment: Pretty sure it's an API, since in context they mentioned other APIs before that.  
But I'd also welcome an answer explaining how to do this yourself with async/await

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/asyncbytes/3767336-lines)?

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe? Seems a bit like it, but that's just for `URLSession`. I would have expected something for `FileHandle`, `String` and/or `Data` so it can be used for local files.

Comment: @YourMJK There is one for `FileHandle` too, but in the documentation it is stated that it is recommended to use the `URLSession` version instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main thing they added that enables this, is `AsyncSequence`. `AsyncSequence` is like `Sequence`, but its `Iterator.next` method is `async throws`.

Specifically, you can use [`URLSession.AsyncBytes.lines`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/asyncbytes/3767336-lines) to get an `AsyncSequence` of the lines in a file.

Suppose you are in an `async throws` method, you can do:

```
let (bytes, response) = try await URLSession.shared.bytes(from: URL(string: "file://...")!)
for try await line in bytes.lines {
    // do something...
}
```

Note that there is also [`FileHandle.AsyncBytes.lines`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/asyncbytes/3766668-lines), but in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/3766681-bytes) it says:

> Rather than creating a `FileHandle` to read a file asynchronously, you can instead use a file:// URL in combination with the async-await methods in `URLSession`. These include the `bytes(for:delegate:)` and `bytes(from:delegate:)` methods that deliver an asynchronous sequence of bytes, and `data(for:delegate:)` and `data(from:delegate:)` to return the file’s entire contents at once.

Comment: This is unavailable on linux, anybody knows an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

The `URL` struct has a variable that returns the destination asynchronously and line-by-line which you can iterate on like:

```
for try await line in URL(string: pathToFile)!.lines { print(line) }
```