# How to read only first part of a file in Swift?

Tags: swift

Reading a file into memory as bytes is easy:

```
let fileURL: URL = ...
Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
```

But that returns *everything*. I want to look at the first 16 bytes of a file, without loading the rest into memory. What's the best way to do this in Swift?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648951/14351818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`FileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) API, which has [`read(upToCount:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/3516317-read):

```
let handle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: someURL)
let first16Bytes: Data? = try handle.read(upToCount: 16)
try handle.close()
```

Alternatively, you can [read the file asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67920531/5133585), in which case you can control how many bytes you read by moving the iterator forward (calling `AsyncIterator.next`), or use `prefix` to get the first bytes.

Comment: Note: 'read(upToCount:)' is only available in iOS 13.4 or newer