# Swift: how can I iterate over the contents of Data one Character at a time (without converting Data to String)

Tags: swift, loops

I have a Data struct whose contents (essentially an array of UInt8) represent the contents of an (arbitrarily large) file on storage. The data is character data and I want to be able to iterate over the data one **Character** at a time (as opposed to one UInt8 at a time). I do **not** want to convert the data to a String, as this could potentially consume a lot of memory (the Data object was creates using mappedIfSafe to try to minimise memory usage). Anyone have any thoughts on how I might achieve this?

Comment: If you have a struct which has properties of type Data and UInt8 and a file it would make sense to show the code for that struct and data and property and file.  It makes it much easier to see how it could be updated to help you out. 

Comment: I assume you also know the encoding?

Comment: Sounds like you are reading a file? If so, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920038/swift-5-5-asynchronously-iterating-line-by-line-through-a-file) help? Rather than using the `AsyncBytes.lines`, use `characters` instead.